# Python - Opening multiple files using open/np.load

Tags: python, numpy

I'm attempting to bring in a range of files - all with a similar name but that have different numbered endings, to work with in a function.

I'm trying to use with open('files' ..... ) as data:
then to work on them but I'm unsure if there is a way to do this without bringing them all in manually.

Is there a way of say, pattern matching on them all so I can work on them all one by one but in the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `glob` to find all the files:

```
from glob import glob
for fle in glob("path_to/foo*[0-9].whatever"):
    # f = np.load...
```

Comment: argh ... seems like you were 3 sec faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
for filename in nameGeneration():
    with open(filename) as data:
        doMyWork(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let's suppose that all your files are called `fileX.csv` where `X` is a number from 1 to 10. The you do something like this.

```
import numpy as np

storage = {}
for i in range(1, 11):
    fname = 'file{}.csv'.format(i)
    storage[fname] = np.loadtxt(fname)
```

Then you can access your data by calling `storage['file1.csv']`.

Or you can also try an dictionary comprehension.

```
storage = {'file{}.csv'.format(i):np.loadtxt('file{}.csv'.format(i))
            for i in range(1, 10)}
```

Which is the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this could be archived with open function. It returns a file object for each file you are opening and it's not possible to pass a list of paths to that function.

What you can do is define a list with paths or a list to manage different file objects. (One for each file you want to open)

```
paths = ['path_1','path_2','path_3']
files = []
for path in paths:
    try:
        files.append(open(path, <mode>))
    except IOError:
        print "File: {}, couldn't be opened or doesn't exist".format(path)
```

Or using with:

```
for path in paths:
    try:
        with open(path, <mode>) as myData:
            my_function(myData)
    except IOError:
        print "File: {}, couldn't be opened or doesn't exist".format(path)
```